# I have two kittens and need an answer on determining hair length

Tags: cats, biology, anatomy, breeds

I have two kittens. One we know will be long haired for sure. The other one I am not sure. Can anyone tell from these two pictures if she will be short- or medium-hair?

We know she won't be long-hair.

[image] [image]

Comment: if you take a picture from the side of your cat with the tail showing it will be easy to answer your question.the pictures do look like short haired cats but to be sure better pictures are needed.

Answer (score 1):

From these pics I’d say short hair!

Comment: I strongly suspect also ;) be funny if it turns out to be fluffy all over

Comment: Would be even cuter lol

Comment: Downv∗ted because of reasons listed in [this Meta Q&A](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777). How did you come to that conclusion of the cat being short-hair? Good answer should provide the thought process so that it is useful for generalized case, not just for the person asking the question. In its current form, this answer does not seem to be of much use for anybody besides the question's author.